# Message order in piped functions

Tags: r

Could anyone explain why the order of the messages is reversed when the following functions are piped? And is there any way to avoid this behavior, while retaining the pipe?

```
f1 <- function(x){
  message("message 1")
  x
}

f2 <- function(x){
  message("message 2")
  x
}

x = 1

x |>
  f1() |>
  f2()
```

Output:

```
message 2

message 1

[1] 1
```

Comment: The order is the correct one if `x |> map_dbl(f1) |> map_dbl(f2)` is used...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What a pipe does is call the function in the RHS with the value in the LHS, for example:

`mtcars |> head()`

This pipe performs the function `head(mtcars)`.

In your code this would come down to `f2(f1(x))`.

Logically if you look at your pipe this way it makes sense that first the `f2()` is handled. What `f2()` does is send a message and call `x`, `x` in this case is `f1(x)`. Only at that point `f1()` gets called which sends a message and then calls `x`, `x` in this function is 1 and this value will be printed.

How you can circumvent this would be by calling x before the message and ending the function with a `return` like so:

```
f1 <- function(x){
  x
  message("message 1")
  return(x)
}

f2 <- function(x){
  x
  message("message 2")
  return(x)
}

x = 1

x |>
  f1() |>
  f2()
```

Comment: I haven't tested this, but isn't evaluating `x`, then calling `return(x)` redundant? At least in this case, since the first line in each function isn't really evaluating anything

Comment: It's actually not redundant in this example because if you don't specify a `return` the function will only return the message, therefore you will get the right order of the messages but you will miss the `[1] 1` at the end.

Comment: Yeah, I meant it seems like you might not need to print `x` on the first line of each function. Shouldn't it get the result if the function just contains `message("message"); return(x)`?

Comment: I thought the operation was equivalent to: x <- f1(x); f2(x) but that's not the case, right?

Comment: @camille ah, you don't print x in the first line, you call x. If you call x before the message the function `f2()` will call `f1()` before printing the message, reversing the order of the messages

Comment: @PhilippeJoly That's indeed not the case. `f2()` pipes to `f1()`, not to `x`

Comment: I understand now, thanks! So, that's because of lazy evaluation. `f1(x)` (_not the result of `f1(x)`_) is passed as an argument to `f2()`. However, within `f2()`, this argument is only evaluated _after_ "message 2."

Comment: Would it be a good strategy to create a function in the form of `pipe_message <- function(x, m){x; message(m); return(x)}` and then calling it like: `x |> pipe_message("message 1") |> f1() |> pipe_message("message 2") |> f2()` ?

Comment: There are many roads that lead to Rome. If this fits your taste you can do it that way but personally I think it might be a bit inefficient, but that doesn't mean it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Compared to a version of wrapping f1 and f2 with map one can see in the AST that there is no extra node in the plain version which might be the reason why the ordering is not be considered:

```r
library(lobstr)
library(magrittr)
library(purrr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'purrr'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:magrittr':
#> 
#>     set_names

f1 <- function(x){
  message("message 1")
  x
}

f2 <- function(x){
  message("message 2")
  x
}

x <- 1
x |> f1() |> f2()
#> message 2
#> message 1
#> [1] 1
x %>% f1() %>% f2()
#> message 2
#> message 1
#> [1] 1
x |> map_dbl(f1) |> map_dbl(f2)
#> message 1
#> message 2
#> [1] 1

ast(x |> f1() |> f2())
#> █─f2 
#> └─█─f1 
#>   └─x
ast(x %>% f1() %>% f2())
#> █─`%>%` 
#> ├─█─`%>%` 
#> │ ├─x 
#> │ └─█─f1 
#> └─█─f2
ast(x |> map_dbl(f1) |> map_dbl(f2))
#> █─map_dbl 
#> ├─█─map_dbl 
#> │ ├─x 
#> │ └─f1 
#> └─f2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>